# ChartJS add tooltip to a grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Iam trying to add an euro sign to the tooltips of my grouped bar chart using ChartJS. Snipped:

```
tooltips: {
   mode: 'label',
   callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
         return data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']] + '€';
      }
   }
}
```

This code works for my linechart, but not for my grouped bar chart. I want my bar chart to look like the following, when I hover it:

[image]

But there is no euro sign in my chart, it just display its value. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

** Edit

So my full options looked like the following:

```
options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Title',
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Wert in €'
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Zeitintervall'
                    }
                }]
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'label',
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            return data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']] + '€';
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```

As soon as i removed the `scales`, it is showing the euro sign.
So my options now look like the following:

```
options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Title'
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'label',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        return data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']] + ' €';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But now i got another problem, it shows the same value for two different bars:
[image]

You can see clearly that the values are not the same. Whats the problem here?

Comment: Are you using Chart.js v2?

Comment: @TomasEglinskas Iam using version 2.7.1

Comment: Was experimenting with a Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r4hrgu4n/ , and I couldn't reproduce, maybe there was a problem elsewhere?

Comment: @TomasEglinskas Oh wow thats weird, I thought I had an error in my logic, but if it worked for you there has to be something else wrong. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Hope it helped!

Comment: Alright i managed it to add the euro sign at the tooltips. But now It seems like we got the same error. If you hover on your charts, you get the same value shown, but obviously this is not the case

Comment: the latest version breaks in IE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be achieved using the following tooltips label callback function :

```
tooltips: {
   mode: 'label',
   callbacks: {
      label: function(t, d) {
         var dstLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
         var yLabel = t.yLabel;
         return dstLabel + ': ' + yLabel + ' €';
      }
   }
}
```

<sup>**FYI:** This has nothing to do with `scales`. It would work perfectly fine along with `scales`</sup>

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'DST1',
         backgroundColor: '#3e95cd',
         data: [3, 2, 4, 5, 1]
      }, {
         label: 'DST2',
         backgroundColor: '#8e5ea2',
         data: [2, 4, 1, 2, 5]
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               stepSize: 1
            }
         }]
      },
      title: {
         display: true,
         text: 'Title'
      },
      tooltips: {
         mode: 'label',
         callbacks: {
            label: function(t, d) {
               var dstLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
               var yLabel = t.yLabel;
               return dstLabel + ': ' + yLabel + ' €';
            }
         }
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your are absolutely right, I just readded the scales and it seems like to work now. I have no idea want went wrong there. Your example for tooltips works great. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but I have recently discovered JavaScript's built-in formatter for currencies, that saves you having to play about with strings and could be helpful here, and is reusable elsewhere in your code!:

```
const gbp = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'GBP',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
});
```

Being English I have of course done it in GBP, but I found that changing the `en-GB` to `de-DE` and the `'GBP'` to `'EUR'` worked absolutely fine. Even formatting the decimal points and thousand separators correctly.

EDIT: including how to actually give the formatter a number to format would be useful wouldn't it!

```
gbp.format(10000); // Returns £10,000.00
```